# Can somebody explain briefly how CORBA and DDS work and their relationship with component framework like CARDAMOM?

Tags: middleware, corba, data-distribution-service

I am new to this kind of architectures and I'm going to start using these shortly, but I can't understand how they work, what they do and their differences.

I've searched online but what I'm looking for is just some kind of small example that helps me understanding the basics.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CORBA](http://www.corba.org) and [DDS](http://www.omg.org/spec/DDS/) are both two open middleware standards for which there are multiple implementations. For both standards there are a lot of resources on the internet.

CARDAMOM is a component framework which is an implementation of the OMG LwCCM standard. It uses CORBA and DDS as underlying communication middleware standards. CARDAMOM is a product of Thales and Selex and there is not a lot of public information about it.

To understand the basics you can try to read the standards but those are not written as user manual. As alternative have a look at [CIAO](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/CIAO.html) and [AXCIOMA](http://www.axcioma.org) which are two alternative implementations of the LwCCM standard. Both also integrate CORBA and DDS as communication middleware but AXCIOMA also integrates ZeroMQ and MQTT as alternative options. CIAO uses the [IDL to C++](http://www.omg.org/spec/CPP/) language mapping where AXCIOMA is using the [IDL to C++11](http://www.omg.org/spec/CPP11/) mapping.